# Clearcase license movement

Tags: licensing, clearcase, host

How can I make clearcase windows client to fetch license from other server then the current one?

Till now I'm using license from our local server (say ABC) but now I want to get the license from a central server (say XYZ). Clearcase server is installed on ABC and all the vobs are also located on ABC. I only want to discontinue getting the license from ABC and get it from XYZ. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the technotes:

- "[About moving ClearCase servers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21129835)" for old ClearCase 2003-7.0
- [Specifying a license host](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_licadm_cc_specify_host.htm) for more recent ClearCase 7.1+-8.x

You can specify the server `XYZ` in the following file/control panel:

> - On Linux and the UNIX system, the license server host name is stored in the file `/var/adm/rational/clearcase/config/license_host`. You can edit this file with any text editor to specify the name of a new license server host.
> - On Windows, the license server host name is specified on the Licensing page of the ClearCase program in Control Panel as the value Use license server on host:.

That supposes:

- you are using the Flexlm license service (and [not the legacy Atria one](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21283862))
- you already have [set up the XYZ license server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_licadm_cc_setup_svr.htm?lang=en).

Comment: Thanks VonC for quick reply. Currently I'm using fixed node atria license service. Also, there is no file called flexlm_host in /var/adm/rational/clearcase/config. I guess i need to create a new one and enter remote server (XYZ) details (like server name and port no. in the file and set the read permission for all the users.
I have also made few changes in the client side clearcase properties licensing tab instead of using atria licensing host, use IBM Rational common licensing (FLEXlm license software).
What more changes do you recommend? TIA

Comment: @rahulbond.007 I recommend switching to Flexlm

Comment: This worked for the "Use ClearCase (Atria) Licensing on host" option too!  (I'm working on switching to the FlexLM server, but I need to upgrade it and that's been a pain; meanwhile, I've got to get off the old server today!)

Comment: @kjpires Well done! Glad to see this 5+ years old answer still being helpful.

Answer (score 0):

@VonC
Thanks for your support. I have successfully moved from using atria license server to flexlm license server. I have removed license_host file as well as license.db file and modified flexlm_host file in ../config directory. I also applied recommended changes in licensing page of Clearcase program in control panel but still it was pointing to old server for license (even after multiple restart). Then I reinstalled client in my machine and entered the details of new license server. it was then that my clearcase client started pointing to new license server for license. Thanks.